MY COINS BEING SENT TO ANOTHER WALLET
So when i deposit 2$ worth of ethereum to pay the transaction fee of usdt erc20 the ethereum i deposit is being sent to another wallet theres someone in wallet or some another thing i can't withdraw coins.

Can you provide your wallet address?

It is very likely that your wallet has been compromised. Usually the mnemonic was used in a rogue website or wallet. Unfortunately there isn't much you can do the "hacker" have a sweeper bot that triggers a withdraw immediately a deposit is made.
